# Google App Engine Push-to-Deploy, does app.yaml have to be in the project root?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a simple Google App Engine project, which includes tests and documentation, structured like this.

```
    project/gae
    project/documentation
    project/test
```

I only want to deploy the contents of project/gae but push-to-deploy expects the app.yaml to be in the root (project), so I would have to deploy the tests and documentation as well.

Is there a way to get push-to-deploy to look for the app.yaml in a sub directory and only deploy that directory?

Comment: app.yaml must be in the root of the appengine project (the running code) , otherwise the appengine runtime couldn't find it.  Rework your project structure if thats a problem, so that docs and tests sit above the gae project.

Comment: Agreed the app.yaml has to be in the root of the GAE project, but push-to-deploy pushes and deploys the entire repository.  It seems the root of the repository and the root of the GAE project have to be the same.  I would like to push the repository but only deploy the part containing the GAE project.  I could use skip_files: but the GAE project would then contain the tests and documentation, which seems confusing.

Comment: The solution you've proposed using `skip_files` is the recommended way of achieving what you describe.  As such, feel free to post a self-answer so that this question can technically be considered answered.